# How do I limit MySQL results only one user id per listing

Tags: mysql

This is my current MySQL table.

```
entry_id   entry_uid   entry_title
-------------------------------------------
1          1           Testing title 1 
2          1           Testing title 2
3          1           Testing title 3
4          2           Testing title 4
5          3           Testing title 5
6          4           Testing title 6
7          4           Testing title 7
8          5           Testing title 8
9          5           Testing title 9
```

I want only one `entry_uid` shown on my result. What is the select statement should I use?

```
SELECT * FROM entry WHERE ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Do you actually mean "only one `entry_uid`", or do you mean "only one **per entry_id**" ?

Comment: It depends: which entry_id's do you want to show then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `GROUP BY` `entry_uid` for this

```
SELECT * FROM entry WHERE GROUP BY entry_uid
```

But it will affect the entry title listing you will be able to get only one entry title , that too more `probably first one`

Answer (score 4):

GROUP the result using GROUP BY

```
  SELECT * FROM entry GROUP BY entry_uid
```